# Replace the first occurence of a text in a given input using Powershell script

Tags: replace, powershell-3.0

The following code works, but it replaces all occurrences of the text that it finds. Is there a way to replace only the first occurrence. I have tried everything for 4 days now.

Please help.

```
cls   
$fileName = "c:\test\bmsbackuplog.htm"  
$findstring=Select-string $fileName -Pattern "The backup of volume system reserved" -list 
$replacement = "<tr><td>Change using this line</td></tr>"    
$firstdata=$findstring[0].Line 
$both="$firstdata$replacement"  
$match ="The backup of volume system reserved*.*"  
(Get-Content ($fileName)) -replace $match,$both | Set-Content "c:\test\bmsbackuplog.htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use zero-width negative lookbehind assertion for that:

```
$fileName = "c:\test\bmsbackuplog.htm"
$pattern = 'The backup of volume system reserved'
$replacement = '$1<tr><td>Change using this line</td></tr>' 
[io.file]::ReadAllText($fileName) -replace "(?<!$pattern[\s\S]*)($pattern)", $replacement
```

Comment: But the patern finds two exact identical entries and I need to be able to use only the first in replacement not both. I do not understand how the above will help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Have you tried it...? I've tested it before posting. No, it won't find same thing twice. Negative lookbehind will make sure the pattern is not present before, hence - it will match only the first appearance.